# Pairing android and arduio via bluetooth fails (maybe)?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I'm using Arduino Mega with HC-06 bluetooth module. I'm trying to just switch a led on and off. I've connected the BT module according to instructions I found on internet (VCC->3.3V, Gnd->Gnd, RXD->TX1, TXD->RX1), but when pairing the devices, the red indicator keeps flashing. I see the BT device on my phone, write the password 1234, on my phone it says "Paired", but the indicator keeps flashing and nothing else happens (I'm trying to turn a led on pin 13 with ArduDroid). Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

The code, I'm uploading to the Arduino. Originally, the code was with Serial not with Serial1, but even then the bluetooth module was blinking after pairing.

```
/*
 PROJECT: ArduDroid 
 PROGRAMMER: Hazim Bitar (techbitar at gmail dot com)
 DATE: Oct 31, 2013
 FILE: ardudroid.ino
 LICENSE: Public domain
*/

#define START_CMD_CHAR '*'
#define END_CMD_CHAR '#'
#define DIV_CMD_CHAR '|'
#define CMD_DIGITALWRITE 10
#define CMD_ANALOGWRITE 11
#define CMD_TEXT 12
#define CMD_READ_ARDUDROID 13
#define MAX_COMMAND 20  // max command number code. used for error checking.
#define MIN_COMMAND 10  // minimum command number code. used for error checking. 
#define IN_STRING_LENGHT 40
#define MAX_ANALOGWRITE 255
#define PIN_HIGH 3
#define PIN_LOW 2

String inText;

void setup() {
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  Serial1.println("ArduDroid 0.12 Alpha by TechBitar (2013)");
  Serial1.flush();
}

void loop()
{
  Serial1.flush();
  int ard_command = 0;
  int pin_num = 0;
  int pin_value = 0;

  char get_char = ' ';  //read serial

  // wait for incoming data
  if (Serial1.available() < 1) return; // if serial empty, return to loop().

  // parse incoming command start flag 
  get_char = Serial1.read();
  if (get_char != START_CMD_CHAR) return; // if no command start flag, return to loop().

  // parse incoming command type
  ard_command = Serial1.parseInt(); // read the command

  // parse incoming pin# and value  
  pin_num = Serial1.parseInt(); // read the pin
  pin_value = Serial1.parseInt();  // read the value

  // 1) GET TEXT COMMAND FROM ARDUDROID
  if (ard_command == CMD_TEXT){   
    inText =""; //clears variable for new input   
    while (Serial1.available())  {
      char c = Serial1.read();  //gets one byte from serial buffer
      delay(5);
      if (c == END_CMD_CHAR) { // if we the complete string has been read
        // add your code here
        break;
      }              
      else {
        if (c !=  DIV_CMD_CHAR) {
          inText += c; 
          delay(5);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // 2) GET digitalWrite DATA FROM ARDUDROID
  if (ard_command == CMD_DIGITALWRITE){  
    if (pin_value == PIN_LOW) pin_value = LOW;
    else if (pin_value == PIN_HIGH) pin_value = HIGH;
    else return; // error in pin value. return. 
    set_digitalwrite( pin_num,  pin_value);  // Uncomment this function if you wish to use 
    return;  // return from start of loop()
  }

  // 3) GET analogWrite DATA FROM ARDUDROID
  if (ard_command == CMD_ANALOGWRITE) {  
    analogWrite(  pin_num, pin_value ); 
    // add your code here
    return;  // Done. return to loop();
  }

  // 4) SEND DATA TO ARDUDROID
  if (ard_command == CMD_READ_ARDUDROID) { 
    // char send_to_android[] = "Place your text here." ;
    // Serial1.println(send_to_android);   // Example: Sending text
    Serial1.print(" Analog 0 = "); 
    Serial1.println(analogRead(A0));  // Example: Read and send Analog pin value to Arduino
    return;  // Done. return to loop();
  }
}

// 2a) select the requested pin# for DigitalWrite action
void set_digitalwrite(int pin_num, int pin_value)
{
  switch (pin_num) {
  case 13:
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(13, pin_value);  
    // add your code here      
    break;
  case 12:
    pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(12, pin_value);   
    // add your code here       
    break;
  case 11:
    pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(11, pin_value);         
    // add your code here 
    break;
  case 10:
    pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(10, pin_value);         
    // add your code here 
    break;
  case 9:
    pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(9, pin_value);         
    // add your code here 
    break;
  case 8:
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(8, pin_value);         
    // add your code here 
    break;
  case 7:
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(7, pin_value);         
    // add your code here 
    break;
  case 6:
    pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(6, pin_value);         
    // add your code here 
    break;
  case 5:
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(5, pin_value); 
    // add your code here       
    break;
  case 4:
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(4, pin_value);         
    // add your code here 
    break;
  case 3:
    pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(3, pin_value);         
    // add your code here 
    break;
  case 2:
    pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(2, pin_value); 
    // add your code here       
    break;      
    // default: 
    // if nothing else matches, do the default
    // default is optional
  } 
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see some code...

Comment: I tought that the code didn't matter in this case. I've added it to the question.